# What does Google do to prevent SQL injections?

Tags: exploit, sql-injection, google

I'm a newbie when it comes to security but I've been interested in SQL injection and in particular in how to protect from them. I've read a lot about how to prevent your website from SQL injections, but I was wondering what Google in particular does to prevent hackers using search. What kind of measures do they take to minimize this (if they do so at all)?

Comment: Google rate limits automated queries. More queries require more money.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SQL Injection doesn't work on Google because they don't use SQL for search - they use BigTables instead (something they wrote)

They do protect against injection in general, however, by using appropriate filtering and never creating queries by combining strings, but rather by passing parameters.  Read [OWASP on SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

They likely use a Web Application Firewall (WAF) at some level as well, just as additional protection against programmer errors.